# Deploy SSRS rdl files on a web server URL without SSDT or Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement where I have built certain number of SSRS reports.
I would like to deploy these reports on a Multiple Servers such as Test, QA and Production. 
Is there any easier way where I can deploy the reports without using Report Manager URL every time I want to update a report.

System Specs:
Visual Studio licensed version 2015
SQL Server 2014
RDL files version used 2010.

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Reporting services provide a web service which can be utilized to deploy reports without having Visual studio or using the Report manager. You can write a script with powershell or c# for deploying. [This](https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/automated-deployment-ssrs-reports-powershell/) is a detailed article on how to deploy SSRS using powershell